# loop through file with hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby, haml

I have a text file located in my project directory that contains the link of sites as well as the location of the logos. For example:

```
img1 = {name => "logo1", link => "http://example.com", imgpath => "img/logo1.png"}
img2 = {name => "logo2", link => "http://foobar.com", imgpath => "img/foobar.png"}
img3 = {name => "logo3", link => "http://foobar.com", imgpath => "img/foobar2.png"}
```

What I would like to do is loop through that text file to display each image with its link. I've searched all over and I can't seem to find a good example on how to do it. Here's the for loop I've got so far in my page:

```
- File.open("img/logos.txt").readlines.each do |name,link,imgpath|
  .col-sm-6.col-md-4.col-lg-3
    .item-work
      .hover
        %img{:alt => "Image", :src => "img/#{imgpath}"}/
        %a.lightbox-image{:href => "#{link}", :title => "Image"}/
        .overlay
      .info
        %a{:href => "#{name}"} #{name}
```

I'm sort of close, the page loads all the logos except the images aren't there and the links are associated with them. I know it's because I didn't call them correctly in my `%img` link and `%a` tags but I can't seem to figure it out. How would you suggest going about doing this?

Comment: readlines is going to turn each one of those lines into a string.  Do you have control over the `img/logos.txt` file, like how the data is stored in there?

Comment: Yea, would it make sense to store it in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#readlines` is going to give you each line of the text file as a string.  Based on your comment, this would word fine:

logos.txt:

```
logo1,http://example.com,img/logo1.png
logo2,http://foobar.com,img/foobar.png
logo3,http://foobar.com,img/foobar2.png
```

Haml:

```
- File.open("img/logos.txt").readlines.each do |line|
  - img = line.split(',').map(&:chomp)
  .col-sm-6.col-md-4.col-lg-3
    .item-work
      .hover
        %img{:alt => "Image", :src => "img/#{img[2]}"}/
        %a.lightbox-image{:href => "#{img[1]}", :title => "Image"}/
        .overlay
      .info
        %a{:href => "#{img[0]}"} #{img[0]}
```

The second line is creating an array of values, like so:

```
[1] pry(main)> line
=> "logo1,http://example.com,img/logo1.png\n"
[2] pry(main)> line.split(',').map(&:chomp)
=> ["logo1", "http://example.com", "img/logo1.png"]
```